# Font awesome icon not displaying

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

On my dot net nuke webpage certain font awesome icons are not displayed. However if I am in editing mode the icons is displayed just fine. But as in the final version of the website the icon is missing. I already checked the version of font awesome and everything seems fine. The website I am talking about is http://www.enio.ch and the icon is on line 1942 in the root html.

Comment: which icon?
i see a couple fa icons on your site

Comment: Have you double checked that you're running the same versions of Font Awesome in "editing mode" and "production mode"?

Comment: it's the fa-object-group which should appear over the h5 tag "Web Applikationsentwicklung"

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. If you are hosting from IIS be shure woff and woff2 mimetypes are configured in IIS.

Comment: Do some icons need woff2 and some are fine with woff? That would explain why only one is not working. But it wouldn't explain why it is fine in editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check angular.js or jquery files?

Comment: What should I check with these frameworks? Are there any code overlaps?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It seems that when I was in edit mode the website used the "normal" javascript and when I was not editing the page the minimized version of the javascript was used. Unfortunately the template that I have is using another version of fa in the normal and the minimized version...